# NPM package.json not updating after npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

i have package.json:

```
{  
    "dependencies":{  
        "package": "^3.3.0"  
    }
}
```

when i transfer this package.json in another folder and run npm install

i get the same package.json even though it should update package to 3.3.2

but when i run npm list   version is 3.3.2
So my question is, why is package.json not updating ?

Answer (score 0):

I just experience a similar issue.
My solution is documented here: [npm install NOT dowloading latest package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437747/npm-install-not-dowloading-latest-package/56437808#56437808)

I think `npm update` should resolve your issue.
You will also find `npm outdated` command quite useful.