# npm install NOT dowloading latest package

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

[context]
I have a problem to use "npm install" command to update my package.json with latest dependencies.

I am running on a Jenkins slave with Multibranch Pipeline, not sure if this is the cause?

There is another post having a similar issue, but not been answered ...
[NPM package.json not updating after npm install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529421/npm-package-json-not-updating-after-npm-install)

Here is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@company/ai-integration-test": "^1.0.1-NIGHTLY",
    "@company/ai-portal": "^1.0.1-NIGHTLY",
    "@company/ai-portal-lambdas": "^1.0.1-NIGHTLY"
  }
```

Here is the result for "npm outdated"
[image: screenshot]
[What do I expect]
I would like to get my package.json by running some command if "npm install" is the correct command to use? Thanks a million !!

Comment: Are you having any shrinkwrap.json or package-lock.json file present when running npm install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found `npm update` command helps me to update package.json to the latest available version. But not sure if I am doing the right things though ... inputs are still welcome !! TKS !!

#### [Final Answer]

It turns out the problem was caused by our company's IT firewall settings.
The firewall intermittently forge SSL certificate for security reasons.
When that happens, downloading latest package fails without giving error messages.

Answer (score 2):

delete your package-lock.json file.

and try npm install again.

But npm install will only update those packages which have "^" in their version, it means auto-update that particular package when you run npm install.

Comment: Actually I always remove package-lock.json in my CICD flow, so this is not the cause of the problem I have, tks.

Answer (score 0):

some of those updates are the major release `npm update` won't update to the latest version.

The major release does not update in this way because they maybe introduce breaking changes. npm save you from that trouble

```
npm install -g npm-check-updates
```

then run it:

```
ncu -u
```

this will update all packages to the latest version in the package.json

Comment: Tks for the extra info. My intention is the update to latest major version, so I use caret ^ symbol.